# Parse enter on clipboard data

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clipboard, clipboarddata

Can anybody tell me how to find if clipboard data contains <kbd>enter</kbd> (next line) and <kbd>tab</kbd> or not

I have code for paste event as:

```
document.addEventListener('paste',function(event){
    if(event.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/plain') > -1){
        var data=event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

I want to print a alert if *data* contains <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> (nextline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = "merry christmas\n"

if(/\n|\t/.test(data)) alert("contains tab or new line")
```

wich would be like that in your code:

```
document.addEventListener('paste',function(event){
    if(event.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/plain') > -1){
        var data=event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        if(/\n|\t/.test(data)) {
            // contains tab or new line
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Comment: does clipboard data also has \n or \t?

Comment: @Madan I added an example for your code, is that ok?

Comment: actually i was building a simple editor using js where i need to handle copy and paste. and i did  this for copy:`document.addEventListener('copy',function(event){
 var copiedData=dataToCopy();
 event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain',copiedData);
 event.preventDefault();
 
});`

Comment: thanks @CodeSir it worked for me now. I made some changes on my code.